# Matching 2 lists

Tags: python

I am trying to match a students name to the the score they got in a test. So I have 2 lists

```
year3studentslist = ['Dave','Tom','Alan']
year3scorelist = ['17','3','12']
```

What happens in my programme is the student logs in completes the test and gets a score. How would I go about matching the name of the student to the score?

Comment: All names are unique?

Answer (score 6):

Using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is probably the simplest way to do it. Doing `zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist)` returns a list of tuples as:

```
[('Dave', '17'), ('Tom', '3'), ('Alan', '12')]
```

So just iterate over this list to access the elements:

```
for student, score in zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist):
    print student, score
```

If you want to access the data by name of the student, you could convert the above zipped data into a dictionary as:

```
data_dict = {item[0]: item[1] for item in zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist)}
```

which is the same as

```
data_dict = dict(zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist))
```

Now you can access 'Dave's' score as `data_dict['Dave']`. But note that, in a dictionary the keys must be unique. In this case, we chose the name of the student to be the key which is not a good idea in the case where there be two Dave's in a class. It is a good idea to use the dictionary approach only when you are assured the names will be unique

Comment: `data_dict = dict(zip(year3studentslist,year3scorelist))` works too.

Comment: @NullUserException I was updating the answer with that :)

Comment: A problem with this though is that say Tom did the test before Dave and got 17. Tom's score will be first in the list and Dave's score will be second.

Comment: @user3369770 In your two lists currently, there is no ordering information. Given two lists with no other info there is no way to correspond a student with a score.

Answer (score 0):

Use python dicts.

Using dictionary is a better approach to what you want to do.

```
>>> Students = {}
>>> Student['Dave'] = 17  # Create the record for Dave
>>> Student['Tom'] = 3    # Create the record for Tom
>>> Student['Alan'] = 17  # Create the record for Alan
>>> Student['Dave'] = 15  # Update record for Dave


>>> print(Students['Dave'])
>>> 15
```

Y you want to obtaing the scores or the student's names separately you can:

```
>>> Students.keys()
>>> ['Dave', 'Tom', 'Alan']
>>> Students.values()
>>> [15, 3, 17]
```

Comment: I think student's name is going to be a poor choice for keys.

Comment: Or ```Students = {student: number for student, number in zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist)}```

Comment: @wnnmaw Or just `dict(zip(year3studentslist, year3scorelist))`.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary you're right. A name can easy be repeated. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` or `dict` object:

```
year3studentslist = ['Dave','Tom','Alan']
year3scorelist = ['17','3','12']
students = {}
for k in range(len(year3studentslist)):
    students[year3studentslist[k]] = year3scorelist[k]

print students
#{'Dave': '17', 'Alan': '12', 'Tom': '3'}
```